# Validation Rules

Tags: database, validation, ms-access, validationrules

So I have a database that I am working on that has a date table that another table has a 2 foreign keys referencing(is this bad practice).  Basically I have to make sure that the value of the first date is smaller than the value of the second but since it only gets the id how do I create validation rules for this.

Comment: Within a trigger (event-driven data macro for MS Access).

Comment: dlookup using the ID as the criteria and return the date(s).  then compare the dates.